# Why is option "--explicitly-allowed-ports" not working when using chrome version 91.x and selenium/chromedriver headless mode?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

We've a lot of selenium based test automation that is triggered by a Jenkins job. The test automation uses chromedriver and headless mode. Some days ago, the chrome installation at the Jenkins node was updated to Version 91.x and the test cases all switched to error state.
We've understood that Chrome now considers several ports as unsafe, e.g. the port 10080 which we use for the system under test. A little research revealed that there is a ChromeOption called "--explicitly-allowed-ports=10080" that should fix this.
For us, it seems to work when running selenium test cases with a browser window, but does not work when running in headless mode. Is this a known issue? Does anyone have an explanation or a workaround for this?

Here is a simplified test case to reproduce the problem:

```
    package com.unsafe.ports;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class UnsafePortsTest {
@Test
public void testUnsafePorts() {
    String url = "http://__SERVER__:10080/__APP__/";
    WebDriver driver = createChromeDriver(true);
    driver.get(url);
    System.out.println("Now at page: " + driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Page source: " + driver.getPageSource());
}

protected WebDriver createChromeDriver(final boolean headless) {
    File driverFile = new File("bin", "chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverFile.getAbsolutePath());
    File chromeExePath = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
    
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    if (chromeExePath.exists()) {
        chromeOptions.setBinary(chromeExePath);
    }
    if (headless) {
        chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
    }
    chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu-compositing");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox-and-elevated");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--hide-scrollbars");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--explicitly-allowed-ports=10080");

    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```

}

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>unsafe-ports</artifactId>
<name>unsafe-ports</name>
<description>unsafe-ports</description>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here are some more specific versions we use:

- Chrome: 91.0.4472.106
- Chromedriver: 91.0.4472.101
- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
- Java: 1.8.0_73-b02

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hope was that it is something temporary with Chrome 90. So I implemented your example above locally but replaced Chrome 90 by Chromium 93. With headless=false everythings works - with headless=true it does not work.
In parallel I implemented a similar test but using Playwright ( which in the background also uses Chromium ): headless=true and headless=false both work, without even mentionning --explicitly-allowed-ports.
Using Chromium directly without --explicitly-allowed-ports gives the error: ERR_UNSAFE_PORT.

My Conclusion: Chrome/Chromium handle unsafe ports correctly ( headless or not ). So probably ChromeDriver does not give the proper information to Chrome.

A workaround would be to install an older version of Chromium and Chromedriver ( Chromium does not implement autoupdate -so you stay at the chosen version ). The page https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/ provides builds for Chromium and ChromeDriver. I have chosen build https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/848870/ which is from end of Jan 2021.  Version 90.0.4404.0 (Entwickler-Build) (64-Bit).
I changed the testproject referencing the corresponding Chromium and Chromedriver: headless=true and headless=false both work. The test asks for pagetitle and page content and the result is:

```
Now at page: Ralfi
Page source: <html><head><title>Ralfi</title></head><body><h1 id="ralf">Hello World!</h1></body></html>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.148 sec
```

Just for reference: The testweb is a small nodesjs.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('<html><head><title>Ralfi</title></head><body><h1 id="ralf">Hello World!</h1></body></html>');
}).listen(10080);
```

Btw: I reduced your Chrome options to only contain the --explicitly-allowed-ports=10080

Comment: Thanks Ralf! I agree to your conclusion that there is an issue with chromedriver. Using the binaries from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/848870/ the issue disappeared. Unfortunately, this means we're stuck to the specific chrome version until chromedriver fixes this. On the other hand chronmium is now bundled in our test project and now we won't have any side effects due to upcoming chrome updates at the Jenkins nodes...

Thx again for your help!